# Adding n <td> to every <tr> in a table

Tags: javascript, html

My purpose is simple is to add 'n' `<td>`  to every `<tr>` in a table.

the problem i am facing is that, it is adding only one `<td>`, not `n` `<td>`, in the last `<tr>` ,not in all `<tr>`, with class 'n'

```js
var actions = function(){
 return {          // this is going to return a long object containg a list of mny function which can be called any time 
  whichPattern: "pattern1",
  addSlots:function(n){
   var e =document.getElementById(this.whichPattern),
    c = e.children[0].children,
    ap_e = document.createElement('td');
     for(var i=0; i<c.length; i++){
      for(var j=0; j<=n; j++){
       var parent = c[i];
       ap_e.setAttribute("class", String(j));
       parent.appendChild(ap_e);
      }
     };
   pattern_config[this.whichPattern].WP_slotsCounter=n;
   //console.log(this);
  },
 }
};

var pattern_config = {
 pattern1:{
  WP_slotsCounter:0,
 },
};

window.onload = actions().addSlots(3)
```

```html
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="actions.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="pattern_body">
<div></div>
<table id="pattern1" border="2">
<tr class="kick instrument">
  <td class='1'>gg</td>
  <td class="2">dd</td>
</tr>
<tr class="snare instrument">
  <td class='1'>vv</td>
  <td class="2">aa</td>
</tr>
<tr class="cymbal instrument">
  <td class='1'>kk</td>
  <td class="2">tt</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: `appendChild` just moves a node in the tree, it doesn't create one. If you want to add multiple copies, clone your node

Comment: @CoqPwner: It's right there in the question's code snippet.

Comment: Really? I don't see any snippet, weird

Comment: @CoqPwner: There's no link that reads "Show code snippet"? That is weird. Try refreshing your page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A node can exist only in one location in the tree at a time.

You can  use `.cloneNode(true)` to make a copy to append.

```
var clone = ap_e.cloneNode(true);
clone.className = String(j);
parent.appendChild(clone);
```

I also changed `setAttribute` to set the `className` property instead.

---

In this particular case, since the node is really pretty simple, you may just want to create it in the same place where you're appending it instead of creating it beforehand and cloning it.